# How do i get profile id's and related data in sailthru?

Tags: .net, sem

I need to pull data from [Sailthru](http://www.sailthru.com/) using .NET API to get following columns:

```
profile_id,
email,
hash,
send_time,
open_time,
click_time,
first_ten_clicks,
first_ten_clicks_time,
purchase_time,
device
```

I have gone through the site also tried few parameters but nothing helped to get data profile wise.

Answer (score 0):

This code fragment should help you :

```
UserRequest request = new UserRequest();
          request.Id = theUsersEmail;
          request.Key = theUsersEmail;
          Hashtable fieldsHashtable = new Hashtable();
          fieldsHashtable.Add("vars", 1);
          request.Fields = fieldsHashtable;

          SailthruResponse response = YourSailthruClientInstance.GetUser(request);

response.HashtableResponse; // This is the keyvalue table where your data is stored
```